# Conflict on Python Django API Deployment

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean-apps

Please, i'm very new to Python and Django, a friend (non developer) reached out to me on deploying django on digitalocean. I've tried troubleshooting some of my issues but dont understand how to solve the latest one:

```
 The conflict is caused by:
            The user requested Django==2.2.16
            django-cors-headers 3.2.1 depends on Django>=1.11
            django-filter 2.0.0 depends on Django>=1.11
            django-phonenumber-field 4.0.0 depends on Django>=1.11.3
            django-rest-knox 3.0.3 depends on django
            django-rq 2.3.2 depends on django>=2.0
            djangorestframework 3.11.1 depends on django>=1.11
            drf-yasg 1.20.0 depends on Django>=2.2.16
            django-rest-logger 1.0.4 depends on Django<=2.2 and >=1.11
        
        To fix this you could try to:
        1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
        2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
        
        ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
 ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

I've tried visiting the address but dont know what to do with the information given.
Please, help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very obvious from the error message if you read it carefully.

`The user requested Django==2.2.16`, but `django-rest-logger 1.0.4 depends on Django<=2.2 and >=1.11`. As the error message suggested, you should either loosen the `Django` version from 2.2.16 to 2.2 or uninstall `django-rest-logger`

Comment: thanks, let me try that. i changed the `Django` version from `2.2.11` to the `2.2.16`

Comment: you should downgrade it to 2.2 (2.2.0)